# VGA temperature is allegedly 511 °C

Tags: amd-radeon, temperature

I'm using HP Probook 450 G2 with AMD Radeon R5 M255 VGA card.

Look at the temperatures (notice 511 °C) and tell me: is this normal or is it just a program lag?

[image: high temperature]

[image: normal temperature]

Comment: Download GPU-z (https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and look at the Sensors tab. It may well be that speccy simply does not understand the sensor it is reading.

Comment: If your CPU was 511 °C it not only would have caught on fire it wouldn't be functional because it would be a pile of non-functional (melted) scrap metal.  511 °C is 5x the thermal limits of the CPU in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it was a proper value, your computer would have caught fire, I think.

Notice: decimal 511 = binary 111111111.

This may be a software bug or a sensor error. I mean: something didn't know what the reading had been, so it set its output to the maximum.

Another possibility: the sensor output was internally correct but out of scope for your software. It's not a big deal if it was low (e.g. booting while inside walk-in freezer). On the other hand if it was high enough to be out of scope for any sane software, the magic smoke would probably have escaped. Try different software maybe and compare.

Modern BIOSes/EFIs monitor temperatures. Such a high reading coming from the sensor should cause your laptop to emergency cut the power. For this reason I would suspect the software rather than the sensor.

Comment: isn't it a funny bug though.. 9 1s.    Like 255/   8 1s,, would be somewhat expected, but 9 1s is a funny one.