# SpeedFan shows ridiculous numbers for Temp2 and Temp3

Tags: temperature, dell-xps, speedfan

I have the Dell XPS 15 (9550). I have recently noticed that my fans seem to be running constantly, so I ran SpeedFan to see if I could figure out why.

[image: SpeedFan showing very high values for Temp2 and Temp3]

Can anybody explain what these numbers mean, and what might have gone wrong inside of my laptop to cause these results?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VGA temperature is allegedly 511 °C](https://superuser.com/questions/1198029/vga-temperature-is-allegedly-511-c)

Comment: It's possible you have no sensors responsible for Temp2 and Temp3 but the software doesn't know this, thus the garbage. I think you can tell SpeedFan to ignore particular "sensors".

Comment: One explanation is that the sensors are failing (or have failed). This might explain the fan running consistently. That said, those particular numbers may or may not be related to something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

The value read by speed fan looks like overflown.
This is most likely an unsigned 32 bits integer value. The max value is 2 to the power of 32, i.e. 4.294.967.296.

The funny thing is the value displayed in your screenshot is not exactly 2^32, it's slitghtly less. How reassuring!

This is most likely a BIOS or a mother board driver bug, causing incorrect values to be exposed in the counter read by the speed fan app.

You can also try to check the temperatures values from the boot menu, or when booting from a linux bootable USB key. This would confirm if this is a windows driver issue.

Then, you can try to apply the latest BIOS and mother board drivers.

Comment: Integer overflow or something similar crossed my mind as well, I’ll try a Linux live USB and see what sort of values that gives me, cheers

Comment: "the value displayed in your screenshot is not exactly 2^32, it's slitghtly less" – No, it's far less; it's about 1/10 of this value. The ideal mapping may be like `output = INT32 / 10 - 273.15` (rounded), where -273.15 is the absolute zero. This way they cover the range from the absolute zero to some insane value with the accuracy of 0.1 degree. In reality the denominator and/or the offset may be slightly different to compensate any known bias of sensors they use. E.g. the formula `output = INT32 / 10 - 281.5` (rounded) would yield the shown value for maximal INT32 (which is `2^32-1`).